# Firestore WriteBatch - what's the point?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

After using Firestore for a while i got used to the habit of wrapping larger database operations into batches. Which can be a little tedious at times and the result is a lot of code to get it done correctly and scalable for sets bigger than the maximum of 500 units (multiple batches).
I adapted this behaviour after reading the documentation on how to delete collections.

This might be a silly question but i was now wondering: if i want to delete lets say 5000 documents from a backend environment and i don't need this to be happening atomically, why wouldn't I simply delete these docs in a simple loop like:

```
for (DocumentSnapshot randomDoc : randomQuery.getDocuments()) {
   randomDoc.getReference().delete();
}
```

What are the advantages of the batched operations besides being atomically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> why wouldn't I simply delete these docs in a simple loop

It is because you'll never know if some of the delete operations that you perform actually fail. That's the main benefit of the [batch writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes):

> In a set of atomic operations, either all of the operations succeed, or none of them are applied.

Comment: Thats true. So its only one listener instead of many. However it would be a great feature if the WriteBatch would do all the logic on its own in a fast and clean way. I love how firestore is so easy to use for beginners like me but as soon as you want to do bigger operations than the maximum 500 of the batch, it gets quite complicated and even the documentation only gives a vague idea on how to deal with it, adding the comment "don't use this in production" (example on deleting collections). I feel like the product would be more complete if a basic function like that would be a no-brainer

Comment: If you have more than 500 documents in a collection, you should create your own mechanism for that. If you have some suggestions, you can send them directly to the Firebase team.